# Xamarin Android Studio doesn't work with Genymotion emulators after upgrade

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

After I have updated xamarin studio from XamarinStudio-5.10.3.27 to any version from 6.0 to 6.2 and to xamarin.android Version: 7.1.0.41 from
Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.3.0.784.msi I meet one stable problem - **any application doesn't work on emulators of Genymotions with message "Could not connect to debugger"**. Or if they allready on device - they are runs and close without any window. But on real devices all works**

And it is for any application. When I try to downgrade xamarin.studio to older than 6.0 -XamarinStudio-5.10.3.27, and downgrade to Xamarin.Android Version: 6.1.2.21 (from package Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.1.2.18.msi) all stay working correctly.

**Even if I made archive signed APK for publishing in PlayStore - it is not running on emulator - only on real devices.**

There log from log cat when i am trying to open app signed apk on emulator krista.iMonitoring/md53237fb1ec257677d7a931761b6317ebe.SplashActivity

```
03-02 12:19:02.850: I/ActivityManager(548): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=krista.iMonitoring/md53237fb1ec257677d7a931761b6317ebe.SplashActivity} from pid 727
03-02 12:19:02.854: W/genymotion_audio(181): out_write() limiting sleep time 46802 to 39909
03-02 12:19:02.982: I/ActivityManager(548): Start proc krista.iMonitoring.process for activity krista.iMonitoring/md53237fb1ec257677d7a931761b6317ebe.SplashActivity: pid=2093 uid=10117 gids={50117, 3003, 1028, 1015}
03-02 12:19:03.010: D/dalvikvm(179): GC_EXPLICIT freed 41K, 4% free 3188K/3312K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 27ms
03-02 12:19:03.022: D/dalvikvm(179): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 4% free 3188K/3312K, paused 5ms+0ms, total 11ms
03-02 12:19:03.038: D/dalvikvm(179): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 4% free 3188K/3312K, paused 3ms+0ms, total 14ms
03-02 12:19:03.098: D/dalvikvm(2093): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/krista.iMonitoring-1/libmonodroid.so 0xa5057790
03-02 12:19:03.098: D/dalvikvm(2093): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/krista.iMonitoring-1/libmonodroid.so 0xa5057790
03-02 12:19:03.110: W/monodroid(2093): Trying to load sgen from: /data/app-lib/krista.iMonitoring-1/libmonosgen-2.0.so
03-02 12:19:03.154: D/Zygote(179): Process 2093 terminated by signal (4)
03-02 12:19:03.186: I/ActivityManager(548): Process krista.iMonitoring.process (pid 2093) has died.
03-02 12:19:03.222: I/ActivityManager(548): Start proc krista.iMonitoring.process for activity krista.iMonitoring/md53237fb1ec257677d7a931761b6317ebe.SplashActivity: pid=2107 uid=10117 gids={50117, 3003, 1028, 1015}
03-02 12:19:03.234: D/MobileDataStateTracker(548): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
03-02 12:19:03.306: D/dalvikvm(2107): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/krista.iMonitoring-1/libmonodroid.so 0xa504e1e0
03-02 12:19:03.306: D/dalvikvm(2107): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/krista.iMonitoring-1/libmonodroid.so 0xa504e1e0
03-02 12:19:03.318: W/monodroid(2107): Trying to load sgen from: /data/app-lib/krista.iMonitoring-1/libmonosgen-2.0.so
03-02 12:19:03.390: D/MobileDataStateTracker(548): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
03-02 12:19:03.394: D/Zygote(179): Process 2107 terminated by signal (4)
03-02 12:19:03.394: I/ActivityManager(548): Process krista.iMonitoring.process (pid 2107) has died.
03-02 12:19:03.422: I/ActivityManager(548): Start proc krista.iMonitoring.process for activity krista.iMonitoring/md53237fb1ec257677d7a931761b6317ebe.SplashActivity: pid=2123 uid=10117 gids={50117, 3003, 1028, 1015}
03-02 12:19:03.470: D/MobileDataStateTracker(548): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
03-02 12:19:03.514: D/dalvikvm(2123): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/krista.iMonitoring-1/libmonodroid.so 0xa504f078
03-02 12:19:03.514: D/dalvikvm(2123): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/krista.iMonitoring-1/libmonodroid.so 0xa504f078
03-02 12:19:03.522: W/monodroid(2123): Trying to load sgen from: /data/app-lib/krista.iMonitoring-1/libmonosgen-2.0.so
03-02 12:19:03.566: D/Zygote(179): Process 2123 terminated by signal (4)
03-02 12:19:03.566: I/ActivityManager(548): Process krista.iMonitoring.process (pid 2123) has died.
03-02 12:19:03.566: W/ActivityManager(548): Force removing ActivityRecord{529ac878 u0 krista.iMonitoring/md53237fb1ec257677d7a931761b6317ebe.SplashActivity t6}: app died, no saved state
03-02 12:19:03.726: W/EGL_genymotion(727): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-02 12:19:03.730: W/InputMethodManagerService(548): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@52ab5228 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@529f3fb8
03-02 12:19:04.338: D/MobileDataStateTracker(548): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
03-02 12:19:04.442: D/MobileDataStateTracker(548): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
```

Onother apk files that were created before upgrade are running
successfuly on emulator, but current version of Xamarin.Studio (6.0 ...
6.2) does not allow this.

Comment: Are you able to deploy and run the projects on other emulators such as the Google AVD?

Comment: check the following http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2016/02/fix-for-could-not-connect-to-debugger.html

Comment: I tryed, It did not help, in article noted that it is case when "Oddly enough, when you start the deployed app on the emulator by clicking on it, it runs fine. The issue is solely the debugger not being able to connect. "

Comment: But in my case even if I try to run signed APK emulator doesn't run it, but real device does it.